# How can I create faq accordions with bootstrap in craft website?

Tags: bootstrap-4, accordion, craftcms

I am trying to create bootstrap accordion in craft website on my faq page how can I achieve that with entries?

Comment: You just need to copy and paste the accordion on this page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ and also have a read of the info on this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First Create Matrix Field for Faqs in the admin section then create subfields for title and description on your faq entry and then follow then add your content in faq page then output the entries with the following code:

```
{% for Faqs in entry.faqs.all() %}
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{count}}">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{count}}"
                            data-target="#collapse{{count}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{Faqs.question}}</button>                                   
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse{{count}}" class="collapse " aria-labelledby="heading{{count}}"
                     data-parent="#accordionExample">
                        <div class="card-body">
                    {{Faqs.answers}}                        
                     </div>
                    </div>
            
                </div>
                                {% set count= count+1 %}

                {% endfor %} ``

        
      
    
      {% for Faqs in entry.faqs.all() %}
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" id="heading{{count}}">
                                <h2 class="mb-0">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{count}}"
                                    data-target="#collapse{{count}}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{Faqs.question}}</button>                                   
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse{{count}}" class="collapse " aria-labelledby="heading{{count}}"
                             data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                <div class="card-body">
                            {{Faqs.answers}}                        
                             </div>
                            </div>
                    
                        </div>
                                        {% set count= count+1 %}
        
                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, appreciate it.

We can assist you further with this.

Also,if you have any questions or concerns please let me know.